# Is this possible? - Controlled system equation

Tags: derivatives, recurrence-relations

Does this mathematical equation even make sense.

[image]

This is taken From my controlled system book, where  4.12 doesn't make sense for..

How come is that true??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are confused by the $\partial$ symbol. 
I think in this textbook you can think of is as of simple differential $\rm d$ (not partial derivative)
$$
\frac{{\rm d}T / T}{{\rm d}G / G}
=\frac{\frac{{\rm d} T}{{\rm d}s} / T}{\frac{{\rm d} G}{{\rm d}s} / G}
=\frac{\frac{{\rm d}\log T}{{\rm d}s}}{\frac{{\rm d} \log G}{{\rm d}s}}
=\frac{{\rm d}\log T}{{\rm d} \log G}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a shorthand notation using the Chain Rule.
Try to imagine it as the derivative of ln(f(x)).

Unless I am misunderstanding your confusion

Comment: Ahh guys(or girls).. I love you. 
I was confused about how come 4.12 was even possible, which has been clarified.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to see working backwards.

Start with:
$$\ln(T)$$

Take the differential:
$$ \partial \ln(T)$$

Apply the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial T}{T} $$

So $$\frac{\partial T}{T} = \partial \ln(T) $$